# установка yarn вместе с nvm

Tags: node.js, yarn

установлен nvm

```
nvm ls
        v8.11.3
        v8.11.4
->      v11.1.0
default -> 8.11.4 (-> v8.11.4)
node -> stable (-> v11.1.0) (default)
stable -> 11.1 (-> v11.1.0) (default)
```

yarn устанавливал следуя инструкции
            sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends yarn
но при попытке запустить yarn

```
Yarn requires Node.js 4.0 or higher to be installed.
```

попытался пофиксить данную проблему следуя инструкции Due to the use of nodejs instead of node name in some distros, yarn might complain about node not being installed. A workaround for this is to add an alias in your .bashrc file, like so: alias node=nodejs. This will point yarn to whatever version of node you decide to use. Но данный способ не работает, yarn все равно не видит Node.js хотя он стоит и используется в проекте $ node -v
v11.1.0

Answer (score 0):

Открытие новой сессии мне помогло